# Numpy random choice function gives weird results

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, random

I have a list of numbers  and other list of probabilities which corresponds to these numbers. I am trying to select a number from numbers list based on probability. For this purpose I use random.choice function from NumPy library. 
As far as i know random.choice function doesn't have to select 1st entry based on its probability(it is equals to zero). However after several iteration it selects first entry.

```
>>>  import numpy as np
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>>  p = [0.0, 0.97, 0.97, 0.030000000000000027, 0.030000000000000027]
>>>  np.random.choice(a, 1, p)[0]
1
```

Can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using it wrong. The signature of`choice` is:

```
choice(a, size=None, replace=True, p=None)
```

Therefore use it with a keyword argument:

```
>>> a = np.arange(1, 6)
>>> p = [0, 0.04, 0.9, 0.03, 0.03]
>>> np.random.choice(a, p=p)
3
```

You do:

```
np.random.choice(a, 1, p)
```

That means your `p` is the argument `replace`, not actually `p`.

Furthermore, your probabilities `p` need to sum to `1`.

Comment: I just checked it and corrected my code. Thanks for your point.